# How to expose InfoPath form to a .NET MVC application

Tags: infopath, infopath-forms-services

Is there possible to expose InfoPath form to a .NET MVC application?Can anyone point me to the right resouces or blog posts.Run out of luck with google.bing.com .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.bizsupportonline.net/blog/2009/10/display-infopath-forms-asp-net-web-page/

That page has info on integrating in a infopath form into a ASP.net application, it should be relatively similar to do it for a MVC one aswell.